# How to show exceptions on unhandled errors in Q promises

Tags: q

I have noticed that if a `.then()` callback fails due to whatever error (e.g. operation on undefined variable) and there is no `.catch()` associated, the error is silently ignored.

This is quite uncomfortable during development.

For example, this code will exit without showing any error:

```
var Q = require('q');

var promise = Q('something');
promise
.then(function() {
  buggyCode();
})
```

A possible fix would be to manually add an error handler like this, but isn't there anything built-in for that?

```
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error.stack);
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently this is a limitation of Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#the-end).

In order to make error handling slightly more verbose, there is the method `.done()`, which should be called after all other handlers and performs error reporting, similarly to the snippet I posted in my question.

This is less than perfect because it requires every promise-consumer function to call `.done()` in order for this check to work.

Comment: I've found that [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) can raise errors even when `.done()` is not called, making for an easier to use alternative promise library.

Comment: Calling .then() with no error handler should (ideally) be a good way to have an exception thrown instead.

Chrome's native Promises do that, and [RSVP optionally can and soon will by default](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/issues/386).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily a limitation of Q.

Your original example uses a `then()` without a `catch()`, which is kinda an anti-pattern with Q.  `then()` is intended to consume any rejections, or thrown errors, returning a rejected promise itself; this is why you have to "`catch()`" the rejected promise, or it disappears into the void:

```
someFn()
  .then(doStuff)
  .catch(handleError)
```

If your goal is to allow the exception to be thrown, [`done()` is intended for this purpose](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress), as it will bubble up any error thrown within its handler, allowing a more traditional error handling approach:

```
try {
    someFnThatGeneratesAnError().done()
} catch(e) { ... }
```

[As you mentioned](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#the-end), a `done()` is required after the `catch()` to surface any exception the error handler may have thrown, but Q [has a global `onerror`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qonerror) property that allows you to provide a handler for the case when a `done()` isn't handled, so you can omit this from individual calls, and catch them all globally if you prefer.

[Here is an example](https://gist.github.com/mmacmillan/384503715d00c6c0ad7f) that shows error handling using both `catch()` and `onerror`, also showing how `then()` handles errors vs `done()`.